# how to display table data in barcode using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want display my mysql table data field in barcode image

```
<table style="border:none" width="540">
    <tr>
    <?php 
    $exam_fee_stud_regular_subject_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM student_master") 
        or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    while($exam_fee_stud_regular_subject_row = $exam_fee_stud_regular_subject_query->fetch_array()) { 
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td align='center' width="50">
          <?php echo $exam_fee_stud_regular_subject_row['rollno']; ?>
        </td>
        <td align='center' width="50">
          <?php echo $exam_fee_stud_regular_subject_row['stud_name']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

I want display rollno in barcode

Comment: What do you mean by barcode? One of these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Types_of_barcodes

Comment: Look into barcode packages. Learn how  to implement them with a tutorial. I have created a barcode generator but you need to know how they work. research some EAN packages. EAN is a barcode type. In a web application it works almost like a font. Their are lots of tutorials out there

Comment: https://bmpradeep.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/generating-barcode-using-php/

Comment: how to get barcode display of mysql table data

Comment: There are two ways to display 2D barcodes: creating an image on the fly (using the html `<img>` element) and using a font (so using a html `<span>` element, typically). To create an image you best look for an "barcode library" for php, there are plenty around. You typically hand over the text to encode as `GET` parameter, that way you don't have to store the text. Displaying barcodes font based as text is easier and faster, since no image has to be requested and created, but you need to reference a web barcode font in your pages header (see "web fonts").